# how to display c# object in html?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on youtube api v3 to display all the video.

With the new youtube api v3 I got the data in json form then with Deserialize it is converted to c# object.

Now my next challenge is to display the data of the C# object in html page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=3&playlistId=UUecxTX6PCkwvuP7U1a6EJJw&key=AIzaSyB8BFP0N1eRGGhSh4xYYyz43QTBSHhOdy4";

    WebRequest req1 = WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
    WebResponse res1 = req1.GetResponse();
    StreamReader rd1 = new StreamReader(res1.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

    string fileContents1;

    using (StreamReader sr1 = rd1)
    {
        fileContents1 = sr1.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(fileContents1);

    VideoTitle video = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<VideoTitle>(fileContents1);

    Repeater Rpt = base.FindControl("Rpt") as Repeater;
    Rpt.DataSource = video;
    Rpt.DataBind();
}

protected void SetItem(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    Literal title = e.Item.FindControl("Title") as Literal;

    VideoTitle video1 = e.Item.DataItem as VideoTitle;

    title.Text= video1.items[0].snippet.title;

}

//json to c# object helper class
public class PageInfo
{
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public int resultsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class Default
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Maxres
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnails
{
    public Default @default { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public High high { get; set; }
    public Standard standard { get; set; }
    public Maxres maxres { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceId
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string videoId { get; set; }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public string publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string channelId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
    public string channelTitle { get; set; }
    public string playlistId { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public ResourceId resourceId { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
}

public class VideoTitle
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
    public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get is System.NullReferenceException at the below line.
Rpt.DataSource = video;

While debugging if i mouseover on video it shows all the values that video has. Not sure whats wrong. Can anyone help me?

The html code is

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Rpt" OnItemDataBound="SetItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <article>

            <ul class="linkList">
                <li>

                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="Title" />
                    <br />

                </li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

For now just trying to display youtube video title.

Comment: Well, If you're using C#, why do you use the Webbased API? There is a huge C#-Library for YouTube, that works little bit better than this JSON stuff, becuase you already get all your information within C# objects and you can just read the info you want out of the objects and print it into html.

Comment: Iam new to c# and i didnt know this. Can you please give me URL for the reference or example?

Comment: Try this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries?hl=en  
I do not have exact links, just search for "YouTube API v3 for .NET" or something like that.